# Calculating Moving/Rolling Average in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, moving-average

I am using SQL Server 2005.

I have the following table (this is just a simplified numerical example): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cbc81

I would like to fill the `rate_roll` column as follows:

- As you notice, for each date, the value of the column `rate` is the same for all `issueid`. What I want to do is compute the 2-month rolling average for each distinct date. Then I would like to populate the rows of column `rate_roll` using those computed values.

Please note that I do not want to compute the rolling average on an `issueid` basis. In other words, I do not want to do that for each `issueid` at a time. The reason being that, in this case, there is no entry for `issueid` 2 at date 20140131. Therefore, the rolling average would be different for issueid 2 if it is done on an issue by issue basis. I want to compute this average for each distinct date (regardless of the issue) and then just populate the `rate_roll` column.

I have tried doing the following, but this does do the computation on an issue by issue basis, which is not what I want to achieve:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT A.issueid, A.[date], A.rate, AVG(B.mse_m) mse_m_roll
FROM dbo.cmm_backtest A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT *
             FROM dbo.cmm_backtest
             WHERE issueid = A.issueid
             AND [date] BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH,-1,A.[date]) AND A.[date]) B 
GROUP BY A.issueid, A.[date], A.mse_m
```

)

```
UPDATE A
SET A.mse_m_roll = B.mse_m_roll
FROM dbo.cmm_backtest A
INNER JOIN CTE B
ON A.issueid = B.issueid
AND A.[date] = B.[date]
AND A.mse_m = B.mse_m;
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE (date, avgVal)
AS
(
select A.[DATE], AVG(A.rate)as avg
from my_table A
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT *
             FROM dbo.my_table
             WHERE issueid = A.issueid
             AND [date] BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH,-1,A.[date]) AND A.[date]) B 
group by A.[DATE]
)
update my_table
set rate_roll = CTE.avgVal
FROM CTE
inner join my_table m
on CTE.date = m.date
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like this query is doing the proper thing it is supposed to. It actually just copies the value of `rate` to `rate_roll`. I am supposed to compute a 2-month ROLLING/MOVING average for each date

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it still doesn't compute the moving average.